# mysql row count query not working

Tags: php, mysql

I think my problem is in the MySQL sections of my code I need it to count at least one table row to be true and continue the `if` statement otherwise do the `else` statement. When I run the code it does not display an error just a blank page besides the username and password `echo` at the top of the page I was just checking to see if they were passing and they are. My code is below:

```
<?php

$myusername=$_POST['userName']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password']; 

echo $mypassword;
echo "<br>" . $myusername;

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=timecard', 'username', 'password');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees WHERE `userName`= :userName AND `password`= :password');

    $stmt->execute(array(':userName' => $myusername, ':password' => $mypassword));

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

$res = $conn->query($stmt);

if($res->fetchColumn() > 0){


session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Comment: First don't use mysql_* functions, then use relative URI for `header()` function

Comment: You cannot (and need not) use `mysql_real_escape_string()` with PDO. It is incompatible, and requires an open `mysql_connect()`.  The prepared statement does not require escaping params.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and you should see something like _mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established_

Comment: The values of `$myusername,$mypassword` both become empty strings, and your query matches no rows.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie The OP _is_ using PDO, just incorrectly.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski He is using `mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);`

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie Yes, in error, per my earlier comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something worng in the way you manage PDO Statements (see doc http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php). Delete the line containing :

```
$res = $conn->query($stmt);
```

and replace :

```
if($res->fetchColumn() > 0){
```

by :

```
if ($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0) {
```